# Serving static CSS file from a Jersey REST service

Tags: java, css, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have an application running on embedded Tomcat and using Jersey. 
There is a resource class that exposes some endpoints, written like in this tutorial: http://www.sortedset.com/embedded-tomcat-jersey/. 
Everything is working fine, now I would like one of the endpoint methods to output formatted text. 
My method in the resource looks like this:

```
@Path("/res")
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String get(){
    return "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css'></head><body>some text</body></html>";
    }
}
```

I put the style.css in the WebContent folder.
When I access the resource, the text is displaying as expected, but the link to the .css file seams to have no effect.

What could be the problem?

**Update**

After Paul's suggestions in the comments, I tried to add the servlet context path the URL path, but it still is not working

1)

```
@Path("/res")
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String get(@Context ServletContext ctx) {
    String ctxPath = ctx.getContextPath();
    return "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='+"ctxPath"+/style.css'></head><body>some text</body></html>";
    }
}
```

2)

```
String ctxPath = ctx.getRealPath("/");
return "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='+"ctxPath"+style.css'></head><body>some text</body></html>";
```

**Update**

Since the problem could be somewhere here, this is the part of the Main class, where I start the embedded Tomcat and set up the web application

```
public void start() {
    String webappDirLocation = "WebContent/"
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(0);
    Context ctx = tomcat.addWebApp("", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "jersey-container-servlet", resourceConfig()).addMapping("/*");

    //start tomcat
}

 private ServletContainer resourceConfig() {
        return new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(new ResourceLoader().getClasses()));
 }
```

Comment: What is consuming this output?  It is not the responsibility of the **server** to include the stylesheet but the **client** - a browser would make an additional request to get the stylesheet.  As a general statement, JAX-RS is primarily aimed at JSON and/or XML, not HTML/CSS.  That is what Servlets/JSP's are designed for.

Comment: Look at the developer tools in the browser. What is that URL that is being requested for the css file. I think that problem is the the slash in the URL. When you add the slash in the beginning, you are saying relative to the root. "root" means not including the context path. Try to include the context path in the URL after the slash and see what happens.

Comment: Also note that Jersey has a [MVC feature](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html), so you don't need to try to implement it yourself, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand that this shouldn't be done in the service itself, but since I need only once in the whole code this functionality, how can I achieve this without additional features or a jsp? As I understand, the browser should just make the request for the stylesheet at the right path? This means I need the file in the proper location (I read everywhere that it's the WebContent folder) and the link to reference the proper path. See my edit please where I try to include the context path (still not working).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what should I see in the URL to be working? The link that appears in the case 1 is just "/styles.css" (ctx.getContextPath returns nothing), while in the case 2 is the file system path to the .css file (C:\ ... \MyProject\WebContent\styles.css).

Comment: What URL do you access the application? And what about the REST API, what did you use for the servlet url-mapping?

Comment: And please don't "inline edit" your posts like this. It invalidates the entire conversation for this post. What you should do instead is add an **Edit** or **Update** at the bottom of those post, and write there any new information you want to add.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad practice, thank you for the advice!

Comment: I access the resource method at http://localhost:<random-port>/svc/res. I posted another update that should answer the second question.

Comment: Can you verify if the resource (css file) is actually coming through as part of the war generation? If the war isn't being built correctly the resource won't be available.

Comment: Change the mapping from `/*` to `/api/*`. I think this should do the trick. Though this now means that you will need to prefix your API urls with `/api`. The reason we need to do this is because if use `/*`, then Jersey will try to serve _all_ URLs, included the URLs for the static content. And it won't be able to find it. We want the Tomcat server to serve the static content, but to be able to do that, we need to give Jersey a separate base path to differentiate between API calls and all others. Also you can change your HTML link URL to how you originally had it.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thank you! Your explanation made me really understand what's going on, and it's working as you described.